# Why first one is working and others not setting index to zero?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, state-management

I am making a NewsCardComponent which will display slideshow of images provided in an array which will be passed down as a prop. Everytime the component is used, will have a different number of elements in images array. so i put the "imgArr" in src of img as:
`<img src={imgArr[index]}>` 
where "index" is the state and i have to dynamically check if a component has reached to the end of array then setIndex to zero. I have achieved what I wanted but i dont know why all the techniques other than first are not working.

**My useEffect:**

```
useEffect(() => {
const interval = setInterval(() => {
indexResetter();
}, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };

}, []);
```

**Technique 1 (working fine) :**

```
function indexResetter() {
   setIndex((prev) => {       
       let newIndex = prev + 1;       
       if (newIndex > imgArr.length - 1) {                 
           newIndex = 0;       
       }       
      return newIndex;     }); }
```

**Technique 2 (state is not setting to zero but increasing infinitely):**

```
function indexResetter() {
    let newIndex = index + 1;
    if (newIndex === imgArr.length - 1) {
       setIndex(0);
     } else {
       setIndex((prev) => prev + 1);
     }
 }
```

**Technique 3 (same problem with second one):**

```
function indexResetter() {
    if (index >= imgArr.length - 1) {
       setIndex(0);
     } else {
       setIndex((prev) => prev + 1);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, your `useEffect()` runs on initial mount, meaning that the `setInterval()` continues to execute the `indexResetter` function that was defined on the initial render, even after subsequent rerenders when new `indexResetter` have been created. That means the version of the `indexResetter` function that you end up executing only knows about the `index` state upon the initial mount, giving you the issue where your `index` doesn't change.

---

For more details, when you define a function, it stores a reference to the "scope" it's defined in, which includes all the variables defined in that scope:

```
function NewsCardComponent() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  function indexResetter() {
    ...
  }
}
```

When your component above renders, it does the following:

1. The `NewsCardComponent` function gets called, creating a new "scope" (formally an [environment record](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-environment-records)). This scope holds the variables and functions (bindings) such as `index` created within the function.
2. The `indexResetter` function gets created (note: it's just being created, it's not being called yet). This function stores an internal reference to the scope created in step 1. This is called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Later on, when `indexResetter` gets called, it uses the scope that it stored internally at step 2 to work out the value of the `index` variable.

When you update your `index` state using `setIndex()`, your component rerenders, and performs the above two steps 1 and 2 again. When this occurs, it creates a new scope for the `NewsCardComponent` that now holds the updated value of index, as well as creates a new `indexResetter` function. This means that each time you call `setIndex`, you effectively create new versions of the `indexResster` function that can see the new value of `index`. The value of index in the previous `NewsCardComponent` scope is still what it was before,  and so the `indexResetter` function created in the previous render can still only see the old `index` value. The new `index` value is only available in the newly created scope that was created as part of the rerender.

Your problem is that your `useEffect()` only runs on the initial mount of your component, so the function that you're calling within your `setInterval()` is the first `indexResetter` function that was created on the initial mount. As a result, it only has visibility of the value of `index` for when your component initially mounted:

```js
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  indexResetter();
}, 2000);
```

On subsequent rerenders, the `indexResetter` function will be recreated, but the above `setInterval()` will continue to call the version of the `indexResster` function that was defined on the initial render (again due to a closure), which only knows about the `index` state at that time. As a result, the value of `index` within the function ends up always being the initial value.

In your working example, you're using the state setter function to access `prev`, which means you're no longer relying on the `index` value from the surrounding scope of your function. The state setter function will provide you with the most up-to-date value of your state, and so you don't face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

From what I am reading, your use effect only runs during the first render. Put index in the dependency array in your useEffect so that it runs everytime that your index changes

Answer (score 0):

@robinmuhia254 is right!

The index should be passed as a dependency to the useEffect for the change to run whenever the index changes. In that case, all your techniques will result in the same output.

If you do not pass the index dependency, Techniques 2 and 3 will not meet the if-crieria(index doesn't have an updated value, it's 0 always), and the setTimeout will run the else part to increase the counter. Technique 1 works in this case because you do not bank on the index state variable at all for your computations. You compute based on the `prev` value.

I hope that explains!

Btw, Technique 2 has got a logical error. If you set `newIndex = index + 1`, the carousel will start-over before it reaches the last element.

I have made a small demo on your use case where I have also fixed the Technique 2 logic. Please have a look:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1mbtpm?file=src/App.js